# Linking On-Premise Data Gateway to Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, factory, data-gateway

I am trying to connect to an on-premise Oracle database in order to sync some tables to an Azure SQL Server database. I believe that Data Factory is the best tool to use for these kind of bulk data transfer tasks, but I can't see how to connect it to the on-prem data gateway.

The gateway is setup fine, as I can see and use it in Logic Apps. I did try using Logic Apps to perform the task, but it timed out because of the volume of data.

Can Azure Data Factory connect using the data gateway? And, if not, is there a more suitable Azure service that can perform this task?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> Can Azure Data Factory connect using the data gateway? And, if not, is there a more suitable Azure service that can perform this task?

When utilizing Azure Data Factory to access on-premises SQL Server, there is no need to set up any form of data gateway.

Connecting to an Oracle database on-premises and copying data to an Azure SQL database is a relatively simple process with Azure Data Factory (ADF). To access the data, all you have to do is install Self-hosted Integration Runtime (IR) on your own computer. Use this easy, step-by-step [Microsoft official instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) to set up and create a self-hosted integration runtime.

All you have to do is set up your source and destination settings using ADF's Copy data tool after your Self-hosted IR has been built. Run the pipeline using the self-hosted IR that you have generated.

Refer this MS document to [Copy data from and to Oracle by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory) . Easy step-by-step guidance is provided here.